# How is the target_f updated in the Keras solution to the Deep Q-learning Cartpole/Gym algorithm?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, openai-gym

There's a popular solution to the CartPole game using Keras and Deep Q-Learning:
https://keon.github.io/deep-q-learning/

But there's a line of code that's confusing, this same question has been asked in the same article and many people are confused but there's no a complete answer.

They are basically creating a main network but also a target network to try to approximate the Q function.

In this part of the code they are replaying from the buffer to train the target network:

```py
# Sample minibatch from the memory
minibatch = random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)

# Extract informations from each memory
for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:

# if done, make our target reward
target = reward

if not done:
  # predict the future discounted reward
  target = reward + self.gamma * \
           np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0])

# make the agent to approximately map
# the current state to future discounted reward
# We'll call that target_f
target_f = self.model.predict(state)
target_f[0][action] = target

# Train the Neural Net with the state and target_f
self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

What I can't understand is this line:

**target_f[0][action] = target**

In terms of code, the `predict` function is returning a numpy array of arrays, like this one for example:

```
[[-0.2635497   0.03837822]]
```

Writing `target_f[0]` to access the first predicted action is understandable, but why are they using the `[action]`?

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi David and welcome to the community! I think that the [0] is for accessing the array of actions as it is in double brackets. After this you need the action index to update appropriately.

The Q network would have as many outputs as the actions available (in your case 2). Then you want to update the weights of the network **in the output layer that is responsible for estimating the Q that corresponds to the action selected**.  So it seems that you have received a $r(s,action)$ and thus you assign it as target in order to use it for the MSE($Q(s,action)$, $r(s,action)$) between estimation and real reward.

The weights of the other outputs cannot be updated by using the collected $r(s,action)$ as the Q-learning update equation would be wrong so the target remains the same as the prediction (resulting a MSE=0). Think that each of the network's outputs is responsible for estimating the return by performing a particular action, at a particular state. For example the first output is responsible for estimating the return (given input state) for action=left ($Q(s,left)$) and the other for action=right ($Q(s,right)$). You train each network head (output layer) with MSE between real reward and estimation. Each time the reward that is sampled from the environment would be the result of a selected action. Thus you update only the corresponding head by assigning as target the reward sample.